# Fire off Ajax afrter page load with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So here it is, I need to refresh a different page after a php hook is triggered. I have a a button on a different page that has a trigger that every time it is hit it runs a php function.

I don't want to use the on click HTML button function because I don't want to modify the project source code. There is a hook that allows me to trigger php functions every time the button is clicked in the system with my plugin.

I was wondering if there was a way I could add a simple ajax-get to refresh a portion of a page when this handle is triggered in php.

so on the php trigger something like this would happen..

```html
$.ajax({
        url: refresh.php,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(placementid).html(data);
        }};
```

I may not be being clear enough...

I have a php function that fiers everytime a button is clicked on another page. I am wondering if there is a way to run the above ajax finction after the target page has loaded when the php function is tripped.... for instance...

```
page one

<button onclick="lalalal();"> click me </button> 



page 2 

function lalala(){
echo ajax or submit ajax function.... lalala page
}
```

Comment: use javascript function for this ajax and make call to js function when button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: refresh.php,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.reload();
            setTimeout(function(){
              $(placementid).html(data);
            },500);
           }};
```

if you want only refresh:

```
$.ajax({
        url: refresh.php,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.reload();
           }};
       });
```

Comment: this would cause a pooling affect and I would only like it to refresh when the php handle is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but, how would I trigger this with my php function? After the page I want to refresh has already loaded.

Comment: maybe in your `refresh.php` method make this:  `header('Location: '.$newURL);` or this: `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`